# Partial with login and page logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a navigation bar that I want to be a partial. The contents of the nav bar will vary slightly, like if the user is logged in or if you're on a certain page you might get an extra link.

How do I best deal with providing the data to the partial? Should I pass this in ViewData for every controller?

A list of options would help me the most, because likely I will have to utilize a few different techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a model for it. Create a class `NavModel` which in its constructor gathers all the data it represents (friendly user name, current page, etc.) and publishes them as public properties. Then just bind the model to the view as usual. Oh, and avoid instantiating nav model directly in a view, instead create a controller action (called Nav) which instantiates the `NavModel` and  returns the nav partial view. Mark that action as `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` so that it can't be requested by the client. Then use `@Html.RenderAction` in the view that needs to render the nav partial (usually a layout view).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem sometime ago, when i have to show some menu to admin and some menu to super admin and some to others...  What i did in that case. I made a an action returning partial view and rendered it on master page. The view was strongly typed. ( A class whose property representing roles of user.) so using that strongly typed class i wrote if and else if logic in my razor view..and that solved my problem....Hope this would help you.